# PHP: Prevent repeating nested foreach multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have been trying to loop nested `foreach` loops but the problem is first `foreach` loop records repeating as the count of second `foreach` loop
first array is coming from `mysql` data and second array I have wrote below, In my case i want to loop the color presets in second array with first `foreach` loop results. I'm not much good in arrays please help me to solve this issue.
here is the second array and code :

```
$colors = array ( 
        0 => array ("id"=> 0, "dark" => "#16a085", "light" => "#1ABC9C"),
        1 => array ("id"=> 1, "dark" => "#2980B9", "light" => "#3498DB "),
 );
$unique = array_unique($colors, SORT_REGULAR);
          foreach ($skill as $skilldata) {
                 foreach ($unique as $key => $val) {

  <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="<?php echo $skilldata['js_skill_perc'].'%'; ?>">
    <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: <?php echo $val['dark']?>;">
    <span><?php echo $skilldata['js_skill_title']; ?></span></div>
    <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background-color: <?php echo $val['light']?>; width: <?php echo $skilldata['js_skill_perc'].'%'; ?>;"></div>
    <div class="skill-bar-percent"><?php echo $skilldata['js_skill_perc'].'%'; ?></div>
 </div>

<?php }} ?>
```

Output should be like : HTML5 (green) PHP(blue) and SEO (green)
but this is how output looks like:

[image]

Comment: What is the content of `$skill`? Your question is not very clear... What is the output you wanted?

Comment: as shown as image that's comming from `mysql` data(HTML, PHP, SEO)

Comment: This question is not too clear to me also. Can you show me the expected output? Do you want HTML5 (green) PHP(blue) and SEO (green)?

Comment: @lolka_bolka yeah exactly thats what I want and by the way sorry about my English

Comment: @AlanMachado I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You need to just switch the colors from line to line, You can use CSS for this (see `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)`) or do it in PHP like this:

```
$colors = array(
    ...
);
$colors_count = count($colors);
$colors_index = 0;
foreach ($skill as $skilldata) {

    $color = $colors[$colors_index % $colors_count];
    $colors_index++;

    echo ... whatever using $color ...
}
```